# What is the difference between "I just got out of the bathroom" and "I have just gotten out of the bathroom"?

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context

If I want to tell someone that I just left the bathroom, could I use the following sentences?

> 1 I just got out of the bathroom
>
> 2 I have just gotten out of the bathroom

If both they are wrong, then what is the difference between 1 and 2?

Comment: As a British English speaker, I would say "I've just got out of the bathroom". I'll leave it to the Americans to explain whether or not they would use _gotten_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer - the one with "gotten" is incorrect.

"Got" is the past tense of "to get", but "get" has at least two meanings - it can mean to have or receive something, but also to reach something such as a place, for example, "I got home".

"Gotten" is used *when talking about the acquisition of something*, for example "ill-gotten gains". It is not appropriate when talking about getting somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Those are both perfectly fine. There is no difference in semantics or nuance.